# Can't use heroku domain as a redirect URI

Tags: python, redirect, heroku, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I have a web-application running at http://chainofthought.herokuapp.com/ and I want to use the Gmail API + OAuth2 to read in and display users' emails.

I have followed the instructions in https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python and have successfully added localhost as a redirect URI.

However when I push up my changes to Heroku I get an internal server error, even though I include the new redirect URIs.

Does anyone know any potential reason why this would be this case?

Here is a screengrab of the authorized redirect URIs I have.

[image]][1
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just guessing here :) You have not specified a port in your two heroku uris. Could that be it?

Comment: Two thoughts - 1) can you share any stack trace (should be viewable through the `heroku logs` command 2) did you verify `google-api-python-client` is in your requirements.txt?